# avoid passing native type in typescript in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that receive style or any other native html attribute, how can I avoid to declaring their obvious attribute type?

```
function Question({style}:{style:string}) {
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      something
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think I can extend HTMLsomething (I forgot), so that native type like style, type, name don't have to declare the obvious type.

Comment: `style`, in particular, **isn't** a string in JSX...

Comment: I can use React.CSSProperties too, for `type` I have to manual cast to undefined | string | number

Answer (score 0):

First off, `style`, in particular, **isn't** a string in JSX. It's an object, like the `style` property on a DOM element (and not like the `style` attribute in HTML; JSX != HTML).

If you want to declare that your component accepts all the usual HTML attributes, you can use the `HTMLAttributes<T>` type defined in React's `index.d.ts` (and/or `SVGAttributes<T>` for SVG). That's how React types its own `DOMElement` interface's props, for instance.